# Javascript advanced event bubbling

Tags: javascript, events

Most of my work has been jQuery, but I'm reverting to "old school" js, as it were, for an upcoming project (REQUIREMENT - NO JQUERY OR OTHER LIBRARY - beyond my control, don't go saying "use jQuery"). My scope is purely the latest browsers, including iOS safari, no need for backwards compatibility. I'm looking at event handlers - and I had an idea that's probably crazy but I can't find anything relevant - probably because it's crazy.

1. I'm trying to avoid binding events directly to elements, since I will be replacing content often with AJAX calls.
2. My current train of thought is to bind listeners to the document. Seems pretty standard practice.

But, can I skip all the event bubbling? Can I somehow tell the browser to forget what it knows about event bubbling, and skip directly to the document? I realize that I wouldn't be able to handle events assigned to parent elements if I did this, but I can live with that considering the project scope, especially if it can increase browser proficiency.

Comment: I could bind some sort of "catchall" function to each individual element and stop propagation, then send the event info to the document, but then that defeats the purpose.

Comment: Why bother? It's not going to have reduced performance...

Comment: @Shmiddty: Of course it'll reduce performance, not even marginally! Binding individual handlers not only weighs down the event cycle, but the question mentions contents from AJAX calls. Binding individual handlers would mean: parsing the response, attaching handlers and _then_ adding it to the DOM, but only after checking what (if any) elements are removed from the DOM, and unbinding those handlers. This requires a lot more work compared to 1 listener that invokes a handler in the _capturing_ phase, surely!

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem He's not talking about binding individual event handlers. He's talking about binding one handler to the document, and finding a way to "skip all the event bubbling". This simply isn't necessary.

Comment: @Shmiddty: I thought your comment was a response to _"I could bind some sort of "catchall" function to each individual element and stop propagation"_. As far as skipping the bubble phase goes, there might just be a slight performance difference (event object needn't be passed down the DOM to the target element) but as the code responsible for that is written in C(++), it'll probably outperform anything you do in JS to bypass that. If that's what you meant then, yes, I suspect nobody can argue with that :)

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Nah, I was responding to the OP. :P

Comment: Thought I should respond here again:
@EliasVanOotegem inspired me with the article he linked. I am listening for events as they enter the capturing phase, on the document, stopping propagation, and accessing the event target to get triggering element. A small optimization, but lots of small ones add up to something big. Thanks much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Skipping the bubbling phase is not an option, really. But since you're only looking to support modern browsers, you could simply capture the events at the top (`document`) level, and invoke the `stopPropagation` method.
That way, the event never gets down to the target/srcElement, and will never reach the bubbling phase:

```
document.body.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
    e.stopPropagation();
    //handle event
},true);//<-- true for capturing
```

More on capturing, as ever, [is to be found on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)

Comment: Very well explained, and thank you for the link. I did not realize that the event handler was "captured" before it "bubbled" in modern browsers implementations.

Comment: @RandyHall: Always happy to help. I thought about pasting the ASCII diagram you can find under the title _W3C model_ on that linked page, to make it even clearer, but I though it better to give you the full page. Just 1 thing: the handler isn't captured, it's the _event itself_. During the capturing phase, the DOM and all elements are _"frozen"_ in the state they were in just before the event fired, the handler is the function that allows you to manipulate that event prior to its actual execution...

Answer (score 1):

> can I skip all the event bubbling?

No. Browsers don't provide a way to do that.